# Interlocked.Increment of Reflected Value Type

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, reflection, synchronization

I want to increment integer members of an object using Interlocked.Increment, but I want to reference those integers via reflection.  Example code I have, which is not working, is below.

```
public class StatBoard
{

    #region States (count of)
    public int Active;
    public int Contacting;
    public int Polling;
    public int Connected;
    public int Waiting;
    public int Idle;
    #endregion

    protected IEnumerable<FieldInfo> states;

    public StatBoard()
    {
        Type foo = GetType();
        FieldInfo[] fields = foo.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance & BindingFlags.Public);

        states = from n in fields
                     where n.FieldType == typeof(int)
                     select n;

    }

    public void UpdateState(string key)
    {
        FieldInfo statusType = states.First( 
            i => i.Name == key
        );

        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref (int)statusType.GetValue(this));
    }

}
```

How do I modify the UpdateState method to make this work?

Comment: Why not use a lock/monitor in the first place? If you're doing reflection, the performance benefit of Interlocked.Increment() may not be visible anyway. Besides, you cannot be sure that someone else is modifying the same variable (with or w/o reflection) at the same time (regardless on how you lock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work by design.  An int is a value type.  The GetValue() method returns a copy of the int.  You'll increment that copy, not the original.  Reflection doesn't have any way to get a reference to a value type value.

Comment: He could use `Reflection.Emit` in a `DynamicMethod` to access the field type. It would be complex and slow, though.